# Parsing Decimals from a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, trim

I have a dropdownlist on a web form that has an item name and a price associated with it (which is not visible to the user).  I am using selecteditem.Text and selectedvalue to capture the item  name and the price.  To combat duplicate entries for the selectedvalue I am storing entries like so

> Signed Cap 10.0
>   Signed Glove 10.1
>   Signed Shirt 10.2
>   Bat Shavings .50
>   Hat Brim .50

Then parsing it out by using the below

```
String[] str = dropdownlist1.SelectedValue.ToString().Split('.');
String itemprice = str[0].Trim();
```

My syntax works great, EXCEPT for the decimal values!  On Bat Shavings and Hat Brim I need to retain the decimal value!  What should I alter or how should I set up my syntax to allow duplicate selected values or to keep the decimals?  I understand that using str[0] is what is causing me to loose the decimals, **BUT** how can I work around it for the 2 (possibly more in the future) scenarios where they need to be remain in tact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell from your posting how your getting your data, but I would load my data from the database into a data object, then bind that object to the drop down list.

**Here is the Inventory Class I used to store the data from the database:**

```
public class Inventory
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }

    public Inventory(int ID, string Description, decimal Price)
    {
        this.ProductID = ID;
        this.ProductDescription = Description;
        this.ProductPrice = Price;
    }

    public string DDLValue
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", ProductID, ProductDescription, ProductPrice);
        }
    }

    public string DDLText
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} [{1}]", ProductDescription, ProductPrice.ToString("C"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is a sample of how to configure the page control:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server" DataValueField="DDLValue" DataTextField="DDLText" />
```

**In the page code behind, load your data into the drop down:**

```
protected void LoadProductsFromDatabase()
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<Inventory> My_DDL_Datasource = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Inventory>();

        // write your code to pull database values
        // populating list with sample data for stackoverflow
        // make sure to use a replace statement to remove any delimiter characters that may be in the description
        My_DDL_Datasource.Add(new Inventory(1, "Product 1".Replace("|", ""), 0.50m));
        My_DDL_Datasource.Add(new Inventory(2, "Product 2".Replace("|", ""), 1.50m));
        My_DDL_Datasource.Add(new Inventory(3, "Product 3".Replace("|", ""), 0.50m));
        My_DDL_Datasource.Add(new Inventory(4, "Product 4".Replace("|", ""), 10.50m));

        ddlProducts.DataSource = My_DDL_Datasource;
        ddlProducts.DataBind();
    }
```

**In the page code behind, create a method to get your drop down list selected value:**

```
protected Inventory GetSelectedProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ddlProducts.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                // do nothing, fall thru will return null
            }
            else
            {
                string[] DDLValue = ddlProducts.SelectedValue.Split('|');

                int ivalue = 0;
                int.TryParse(DDLValue.GetValue(0).ToString(), out ivalue);

                decimal dvalue = 0.00m;
                decimal.TryParse(DDLValue.GetValue(2).ToString(), out dvalue);

                // only return object if the productid and product price were successfully parsed.
                // this logic assumes no products are free
                if (ivalue > 0 && dvalue > 0.00m)
                {
                    return new Inventory(ivalue, DDLValue.GetValue(1).ToString(), dvalue);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
```

**In the page code behind, do something with your selected value:**

```
protected void DoSomethingWithValue()
    {
        Inventory MyInventoryItem = GetSelectedProduct();

        if (MyInventoryItem != null)
        {
            // selected item successfully parsed
            // do something with it.

            Response.Write(
                string.Format("Your selected product:<br />{0}<br />UniqueID: {1}<br />Price: {2}",
                Server.HtmlEncode(MyInventoryItem.ProductDescription),
                MyInventoryItem.ProductID,
                MyInventoryItem.ProductPrice.ToString("C")
            ));
        }
        else
        {
            // error parsing information stored in drop down list value
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on space, and always take the last entry using linq:

```
dropdownlist1.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(' ').Last();
```

Note you should be using a hidden ItemId as the selectedvalue, instead of item name and price, and use a lookup table of:

```
ItemId|Name|Price
1|Hat|.50
2|Bat Shavings|.50
...
```

When the selected id is submitted you can lookup the name and price more directly.  Also, the price being hidden in a form doesn't prevent the user from manipulating the price.

Comment: the actual lookup is coming from a SQL Server Table.  Shoudl I still be worried about a user manipulating the price?  I also do not want to always take the .Last() from the string, I only want to take the .Last when their is not a whole number to the left of the decimal.

Comment: How does this relate to people manipulating the price? In any case, you should *never* accept user input without validating it against the database (for fields a user shouldn't be able to choose).

Comment: @InformationRequested "I also do not want to always take the .Last() from the string, I only want to take the .Last when their is not a whole number to the left of the decimal."  You would always want to take last. Whether there is a whole number or decimal following the space, you want the price right?  What does it matter whether it's whole number or not?  It follows the space.

Comment: @InformationRequested If you split "Signed Cap 10.0" on spaces, the last item will be "10.0", so it will work either way.

Comment: @InformationRequested And yes you should worry, because even though you populated the dropdown from a lookup table, you've designed it such that you are trusting the price that is sent from the user's client, rather than using an ID and looking up the price in the DB.  Like I said, use an ID for the selected value and lookup the price AFTER the request server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove/replace all alpha characters from string and keep only numeric.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");
str = rgx.Replace(str, "").Trim();
decimal prc;
Decimal.TryParse(str, out prc);
```